# Failing to load resources in the angular production environment

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get an app made with the angular-cli on to a server. I used the command `ng build --environment=production` which built without any errors. The `ng serve` command throws no errors, but when I try to load the page locally, I get this error in the Google Chrome console [saying that it can't find the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0OiY.png) The paths in the index.html look like this [which should be correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raA69.png)

Thanks

Comment: The issue was in the `<base>` tag. I had set it to be `/` when it should have been the project path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a library of mine. Mangling the production code is what's causing the issue. It's an issue with angular and not your application.

This is how we solve it:

Location: `ngular-cli/addon/ng2/models/webpack-build-production.ts`

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    beautify: false,
    mangle: false, // Workaround for some modules with issues when mangling
    compress: {
        screw_ie8: true,
    },
    comments: false
}),
```

And here is the link to the [issue](https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/issues/60)